Persistent 403 Forbidden Error After Configuring DNS and SSL for Canva Integration
Title:
"Help Needed: Persistent 403 Forbidden Error After Configuring DNS and SSL for Canva Integration"
Body:
Hello Reddit community,
I'm reaching out for help with an issue that's been bugging me for a while now. I'm trying to configure my domain (aegcksa.com) to point to Canva, but I'm running into persistent problems. Here’s the full situation:
Background:

Domain Provider: Hostinger
Current Setup:

A records for @ (root domain) and www point to 103.169.142.0 as required by Canva.
TXT record for Canva domain verification is correctly set and shows as "Connected" on Canva.
SSL certificate (ZeroSSL) is installed and active.
DNS records verified multiple times for accuracy.



Current DNS Settings:

TXT _canva-domain-verify  "1cf649b3-12a4-4969-b0d8-e7ee68138f0e"  TTL: 14400
CNAME hostingermail-c._domainkey hostingermail-c.dkim.mail.hostinger.com TTL: 300
CNAME hostingermail-b._domainkey hostingermail-b.dkim.mail.hostinger.com TTL: 300
CNAME hostingermail-a._domainkey hostingermail-a.dkim.mail.hostinger.com TTL: 300
A www 103.169.142.0 TTL: 14400
CNAME autodiscover autodiscover.mail.hostinger.com TTL: 300
CNAME autoconfig autoconfig.mail.hostinger.com TTL: 300
TXT _dmarc "v=DMARC1; p=none" TTL: 3600
CAA @ 0 issuewild "globalsign.com" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issuewild "letsencrypt.org" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issuewild "digicert.com" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issuewild "comodoca.com" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issue "letsencrypt.org" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issue "globalsign.com" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issue "digicert.com" TTL: 14400
CAA @ 0 issue "comodoca.com" TTL: 14400
AAAA @ 2a02:4780:2b:1486:0:2e09:4060:2 TTL: 1800
TXT @ "v=spf1 include:_spf.mail.hostinger.com ~all" TTL: 3600
MX @ mx1.hostinger.com Priority: 5 TTL: 14400
MX @ mx2.hostinger.com Priority: 10 TTL: 14400
A @ 103.169.142.0 TTL: 14400

Problems Encountered:

Canva Verification:

Canva shows the A record for the root domain (@) as "Not Found" and status is "Pending".
A record for www is "Connected".


Website Access:

When accessing the website, I get a "403 Forbidden" error.
I accidentally deleted the .htaccess file but have since recreated it with basic settings.



Steps Taken So Far:

Verified DNS Settings:

Double-checked that A records for @ and www point to 103.169.142.0.


Checked File Permissions:

Ensured directories have 755 permissions and files have 644 permissions.


Reviewed Server Logs:

No specific errors found related to the "403 Forbidden" error.


SSL Configuration:

SSL certificate (ZeroSSL) is active.
TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 are enabled, and older protocols are disabled.


.htaccess File Configuration:

Created a new .htaccess file with basic rules to force HTTPS and handle index files.



Despite these steps, I'm still facing the "403 Forbidden" error and Canva shows the root A record as "Pending".
Request:
I would greatly appreciate any advice or suggestions on what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them. Specifically:

How can I fix the "403 Forbidden" error?
Why might Canva still show the A record for @ as "Pending"?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide!
